# Applescript to extract text in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text, applescript, csv

I need to get a lit of number from Chrome,

The number of item is randoms, so I guess, I need to use a repeat statement

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell front window's active tab to set MyPersonalID to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('sortable PersonId')[1].innerHTML;"
end tell
```

This for example is the first number I need (start with ('sortable PersonId')[1] then [2], [3] etc)

also the result of this snippet is

Result:

```
"

                                    112511721165

                            "
```

I don't need the random space, so the best option for me would be a result like below :

112511721165, 21241171169, etc...

I tried to get rid of the space with the following script but with no success :

```
set theText to Unicode text
set theSource to Grabber
property leftEdge71 : "

                                    "
property rightEdge71 : "

                            "
try
    set saveTID to text item delimiters
    set text item delimiters to leftEdge71
    set classValue to text item 2 of theSource
    set text item delimiters to rightEdge71
    set purchaseDate to text item 1 of classValue
    set text item delimiters to saveTID
    Result
end try
```

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE :

```
set NumberList to my getInputByClass2("sortable PersonId", 1)


to getInputByClass2(theClass)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell front window's active tab to set r to execute javascript "var outPut=[]; var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "');for (var i in arr) {outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)};outPut;"
    end tell
    return strings of r 
end getInputByClass2
```

This get the list of number I want, but still return the 1st result with is a random invalid URL and still have a lot of space in-between the result.

For the first item I use:

```
items 2 thru -1 of NumberList
```

but I don't managed to remove the empty space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no URL to test any of the JavaScript against, this answer is to show  how to remove the *spaces* and *linefeeds* from the *value* of the `MyPersonalID` *variable*.

In cases like this, I'll often use the `do shell script` *command* and a *command line utility*, as it's just quick and easy me.

**Code:**

```
set MyPersonalID to "

                                    112511721165

                            "

set MyPersonalID to do shell script "awk '/[0-9]/{printf $1}'<<<" & quoted form of MyPersonalID
```

**Events:**

```
tell current application
    do shell script "awk '/[0-9]/{printf $1}'<<<'

                                112511721165

                        '"
        --> "112511721165"
end tell
Result:
"112511721165"
```

If you want to do it in *so called pure* AppleScript:

**Code:**

```
set MyPersonalID to "

                                    112511721165

                            "


my cleanUp(MyPersonalID)


on cleanUp(theText)
    --  # Remove spaces from text.
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" "}
    set theText to text items of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
    set theText to theText as text
    --  # Remove linefeeds from text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {linefeed}
    set theText to text items of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
    set theText to theText as text
    return theText
end cleanUp
```

**Events:**

```
Result:
"112511721165"
```

Comment: Thank you, trying all this now.

Comment: That great thank you, for some reason I keep having the first invalid result though. also can I change the line return to a coma ?

Comment: @KevinCork, As I stated in my answer "Since there is no URL to test any of the JavaScript against, this answer is to show how to remove the _spaces_ and _linefeeds_ from the _value_ of the `MyPersonalID` _variable_.", and this was based solely on the _value_ you showed for "Result:" and this is just _example code_ and not meant to be a complete working solution. Can it be modified to do something else, yes, of course it can. However, it is not totally clear what you want and to be fair,you might consider starting a new question and provide the relevant details.

Answer (score 2):

You get a string from a JavaScript's method, use the JavaScript's `trim()` method to removes whitespaces from both ends of a string.

Like this: `.innerHTML.trim()`

Or better: `.innerText.trim()`

Comment: Will `.innerHTML.trim()` also remove the linefeeds or will `.innerText.trim()` do that?

Comment: The `trim()` method removes (space, tab, etc.) and all the line terminator characters from both sides of any string. The `innerHTM` method returns a string, representing the **HTML** content of an element object, but if the element object contains  one node or more nodes, the string will contains **HTML** tags. The `innerText` method returns the plain text of an element object, but, if the element object contains one node or more nodes, the **HTML** tags are simply stripped.
A similar method `.textContent` : returns the textual content of the element object, and all its descendants.